# DateTimePicker Date On DataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, datagridview, datetimepicker

```
mtxtBdate.Value = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["Birthdate"].Value.ToString();
```

I use this syntax on DataGridView in all other textboxes - but can someone tell me how to adapt this DatePicker control syntax? I want to get the date that user selects on the `DateTimePicker` that is show on the datagrid.

```
mtxtfname.text = datagridView1.SelectRows[0].Cells["fIrstname"].value.ToString();
```

This syntax will work for text box but for data picker?

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the combination of a `<asp:TextBox>` and `<asp:CalendarExtender>` control that targets a textbox where the selected date will be added

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBirthdate" runat="server"  
            CssClass="contentfield" Height="16px" MaxLength="12" 
             width="150px" Wrap="False"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" 
            Format="dd MMM yyyy" PopupButtonID="imgSummaryCashFlowDate" 
            TargetControlID="txtBirthdate">
        </asp:CalendarExtender>
```

This will work exactly the same as a normal textbox in your gridview and you will be able to pull the date from the textbox exactly the same manner as you have done orignally.